# Is there a way to install Google Chrome on Linux and have all the needed dependencies automatically installed?

Tags: linux, google-chrome, rpm, dependencies

I’m trying to install Google chrome on the following version of 64-bit Linux …

```
[davea@mydevbox mydir]$ uname -a
Linux mydevbox.mydomain.com 1.3.8-18.52.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Mar 16 17:15:34 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

After downloading the rpm package and attempting to install, I get the below errors …

```
[davea@mydevbox ~]$ sudo rpm -ivh google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64.rpm 
[sudo] password for davea: 
warning: google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64.rpm: Header V4 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 7fac5991: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
    xdg-utils is needed by google-chrome-stable-49.0.2623.112-1.x86_64
    libatk-1.0.so.0()(64bit) is needed by google-chrome-stable-49.0.2623.112-1.x86_64
    libgconf-2.so.4()(64bit) is needed by google-chrome-stable-49.0.2623.112-1.x86_64
    libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0()(64bit) is needed by google-chrome-stable-49.0.2623.112-1.x86_64
    libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0()(64bit) is needed by google-chrome-stable-49.0.2623.112-1.x86_64
    libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0()(64bit) is needed by google-chrome-stable-49.0.2623.112-1.x86_64
    libpango-1.0.so.0()(64bit) is needed by google-chrome-stable-49.0.2623.112-1.x86_64
    libpangocairo-1.0.so.0()(64bit) is needed by google-chrome-stable-49.0.2623.112-1.x86_64
    libXcomposite.so.1()(64bit) is needed by google-chrome-stable-49.0.2623.112-1.x86_64
    libXcursor.so.1()(64bit) is needed by google-chrome-stable-49.0.2623.112-1.x86_64
    libXrandr.so.2()(64bit) is needed by google-chrome-stable-49.0.2623.112-1.x86_64
```

Another link said I need to have the “lsb” and “libXScrnSaver” installed, which I did through yum.  Is there any way to install Google chrome and have all the dependencies automatically installed for you?

**Edit:** I tried your suggestion, but am getting a bunch of errors about not being able to find dependencies …

```
[davea@mydevbox ~]$ sudo yum --nogpgcheck localinstall google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64.rpm
[sudo] password for davea: 
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
Examining google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64.rpm: google-chrome-stable-49.0.2623.112-1.x86_64
Marking google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64.rpm to be installed
Resolving Dependencies
amzn-main/latest                                                                                                                                                                     |  2.1 kB     00:00     
amzn-updates/latest                                                                                                                                                                  |  2.3 kB     00:00     
--> Running transaction check
---> Package google-chrome-stable.x86_64 0:49.0.2623.112-1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: xdg-utils for package: google-chrome-stable-49.0.2623.112-1.x86_64
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * amzn-main: packages.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
 * amzn-updates: packages.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
--> Processing Dependency: libatk-1.0.so.0()(64bit) for package: google-chrome-stable-49.0.2623.112-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libgconf-2.so.4()(64bit) for package: google-chrome-stable-49.0.2623.112-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0()(64bit) for package: google-chrome-stable-49.0.2623.112-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0()(64bit) for package: google-chrome-stable-49.0.2623.112-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0()(64bit) for package: google-chrome-stable-49.0.2623.112-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libpango-1.0.so.0()(64bit) for package: google-chrome-stable-49.0.2623.112-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libpangocairo-1.0.so.0()(64bit) for package: google-chrome-stable-49.0.2623.112-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libXcomposite.so.1()(64bit) for package: google-chrome-stable-49.0.2623.112-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libXcursor.so.1()(64bit) for package: google-chrome-stable-49.0.2623.112-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libXrandr.so.2()(64bit) for package: google-chrome-stable-49.0.2623.112-1.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package google-chrome-stable.x86_64 0:49.0.2623.112-1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: xdg-utils for package: google-chrome-stable-49.0.2623.112-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libatk-1.0.so.0()(64bit) for package: google-chrome-stable-49.0.2623.112-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libgconf-2.so.4()(64bit) for package: google-chrome-stable-49.0.2623.112-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0()(64bit) for package: google-chrome-stable-49.0.2623.112-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0()(64bit) for package: google-chrome-stable-49.0.2623.112-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0()(64bit) for package: google-chrome-stable-49.0.2623.112-1.x86_64
---> Package libXcomposite.x86_64 0:0.4.3-4.6.amzn1 will be installed
---> Package libXcursor.x86_64 0:1.1.14-2.1.9.amzn1 will be installed
---> Package libXrandr.x86_64 0:1.4.1-2.1.8.amzn1 will be installed
---> Package pango.x86_64 0:1.28.1-10.11.amzn1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libthai >= 0.1.9 for package: pango-1.28.1-10.11.amzn1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libthai.so.0(LIBTHAI_0.1)(64bit) for package: pango-1.28.1-10.11.amzn1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libXft.so.2()(64bit) for package: pango-1.28.1-10.11.amzn1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libthai.so.0()(64bit) for package: pango-1.28.1-10.11.amzn1.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package google-chrome-stable.x86_64 0:49.0.2623.112-1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: xdg-utils for package: google-chrome-stable-49.0.2623.112-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libatk-1.0.so.0()(64bit) for package: google-chrome-stable-49.0.2623.112-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libgconf-2.so.4()(64bit) for package: google-chrome-stable-49.0.2623.112-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0()(64bit) for package: google-chrome-stable-49.0.2623.112-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0()(64bit) for package: google-chrome-stable-49.0.2623.112-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0()(64bit) for package: google-chrome-stable-49.0.2623.112-1.x86_64
---> Package libXft.x86_64 0:2.3.1-2.7.amzn1 will be installed
---> Package libthai.x86_64 0:0.1.12-3.5.amzn1 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: google-chrome-stable-49.0.2623.112-1.x86_64 (/google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64)
           Requires: xdg-utils
Error: Package: google-chrome-stable-49.0.2623.112-1.x86_64 (/google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64)
           Requires: libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: google-chrome-stable-49.0.2623.112-1.x86_64 (/google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64)
           Requires: libatk-1.0.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: google-chrome-stable-49.0.2623.112-1.x86_64 (/google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64)
           Requires: libgconf-2.so.4()(64bit)
Error: Package: google-chrome-stable-49.0.2623.112-1.x86_64 (/google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64)
           Requires: libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: google-chrome-stable-49.0.2623.112-1.x86_64 (/google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64)
           Requires: libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0()(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
** Found 2 pre-existing rpmdb problem(s), 'yum check' output follows:
2000:jdk-1.6.0_45-fcs.x86_64 is a duplicate with 2000:jdk-1.6.0_35-fcs.x86_64
2000:jdk-1.6.0_65-fcs.x86_64 is a duplicate with 2000:jdk-1.6.0_45-fcs.x86_64
```

Comment: Doesn't yum do it? It should with `sudo yum --nogpgcheck localinstall packagename.arch.rpm` but replace "packagename.arch.rpm" with your rpm file

Comment: Google-chrome is a special beast evidently . I get the above errors complaining about missing libraries when I try your suggestion involving yum.

Answer (score 0):

You obviously use Amazon Linux. This is derivate of CentOS. But with some [changes](https://www.exratione.com/2014/08/do-not-use-amazon-linux/). So I'm not sure if your goal is even possible. It is better to use CentOS. But even then - some version of Chrome does not support CentOS, then Google add the support back. IIRC this support/not supported flip happen several times. So you will be save with using Chrome on Fedora. There is even [repository](https://copr.fedorainfracloud.org/coprs/spot/chromium/) with Chromium (free version of Chrome) for Fedora.

Comment: Hi, It is not an option to switch teh version of Linux I use.  My question stands with the given constraints.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the instructions here for 64-bit, using skip-broken to avoid problems on install:

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/using-yum-install-google-chrome-aws-linux-ami-konstantinos-demiris

Beware of bad hyphens in those instructions! Copy and paste to a text editor, then fix all the hyphens before running those commands.